# ¿Cómo hacer que el botón se posicione automáticamente dependiendo del tamaño del formulario?

Tags: html5, formularios, botón

Tengo un formulario y me encuentro con el siguiente problema. Al momento de seleccionar un libro el título de este varía depediendo del que sea seleccionado. Puede contener un título corto o bastante extenso como muestro en las imágenes de ejemplo más abajo. **Mi problema es qué el boton de registrar queda fijo y no se posiciona abajo de la ultima linea del formulario**
Me gustaría qué este mismo cambie su posición dependiendo del tamaño que adopte el formulario o en este caso el título del libro ya qué no sabremos qué tan extenso será.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que el botón valla bajando teniendo en cuenta el tamaño del formulario o del título de libros?

- Recomiendo copiar el código CSS y HTML y pegarlo en un editor propio y ver bien el formulario ya qué no recibe bien los link importados la extension de nuestro foro al momento de correrlo aquí.
- En el código deje comentado un texto extenso y otro no tan extenso para que puedan hacer el test

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

body {
  background: #504157;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}


/* ------------- FORMULARIO ------------- */

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 430px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 11px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.container .forms {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 530px;
  width: 200%;
  transition: height 0.2s ease;
}

.container .form {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: margin-left 0.18s ease;
  border-radius: 11px;
}

.container .form .title {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.form .title::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -9%;
  height: 3px;
  width: 119.7%;
  background-color: #4070f4;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.form .input-field {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.form .bstr button {
  border-color: #4070f4;
  font-display: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #4070f4;
  padding: 11px;
}

.bstr button:hover {
  background-color: #145D56;
  border-color: #145D56;
}

.container .btn2 {
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #145D56;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.container .btn2 i {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2-bootstrap-5-theme@1.3.0/dist/select2-bootstrap-5-theme.min.css" />
  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <!-- ===== CSS ===== -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container" style="margin-left: 6%;">
    <a href="#">
      <button type="button" class="btn2 btn-primary"><i class="uil uil-arrow-circle-left"></i> Inicio</button>
    </a>
    <div class="forms" style="height: 460px;">
      <div class="form login" style="height: 90%;">
        <span class="title" style="margin-bottom: 30%">Registro</span><br><br><br>

        <form method="POST">
          <div class="input-field" style="margin-top: 4%;">

            <!-- TESTEAR CON EL TEXTO CORTO Y EL TEXTO LARGO -->
            <!-- <h4 style="font-size: large;">Libro seleccionado: = Bioquimica</h4> -->
            <h4 style="font-size: large;">Libro seleccionado: = La preparación física en el voleibol y el desarrollo de la fuerza en los deportes de carácter explosivo-balístico.</h4>



            <hr>
            <h4 style="font-size: large;">Fecha de Inicio = 07/03/2023</h4>
            <hr>
            <h4 style="font-size: large;">Fecha de Devolución = 14/03/2023</h4><br><br>
          </div>

          <div class="bstr d-grid col-12 mx-auto" style="margin-top: 17%;">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="botonRegistrar">Registrar</button>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Buenas Lucas, mira los estilos de `.container .forms` (tienes un height fijo ahí puesto), la pantalla no se va a extender hacia abajo para que se posicione puesto que estás diciendo que quieres que sea esa la altura, si lo que quieres es que sea fija la altura deberías poner un overflow: scrollbar o algo así, por otro lado, mira en el código html   `<div class="forms" style="height: 460px;">` ahí también estás definiendo un altura fija

Comment: Los puse fijos para que se posicionara en el centro de la pantalla más o menos porqué sino se posicionaba muy arriba el formulario. Probé ahora la propiedad overflow: scrollbar pero me coloca los scrollbar y en el formulario. Hay otra solución que me recomendes?

Comment: El problema son los anchos fijos... hay que quitar todos los anchos o alturas que tengan tus elementos y hacerlos flexibles para usar space-between...  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content, más luego lo analizo.

Comment: Dale sí necesito que le eches una mirada. Cuando tengas tiempo no tengo problema @Cris223511.dev

Comment: Hola Lucas... cambia **`.form .input-field {`** por **`.form.input-field {`**, y boileau!!!, también deberías corregir los otros errores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a quitar todos los espacios y anchos de tus divs que encierran a tus inputs y a tu botón (que son llamados `input-field` y `bstr`) para evitar que los elementos estén uno encima del otro (esto es más notorio en resoluciones pequeñas), de preferencia es mejor quitarlo:

```
<form method="POST">
  <div class="input-field"> <!-- aquí quito el style="margin-top: 4%;" -->
    <!-- tus inputs -->
  </div>
  <div class="bstr d-grid col-12 mx-auto"> <!-- aquí quito el style="margin-top: 17%;" -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="botonRegistrar">Registrar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Ahora en tu CSS, modifiqué que el contenedor `forms` no tenga una altura fija, sino ocupe todo el alto máximo con la propiedad `max-content`. Esto es para evitar que los elementos de adentro se desborden del contenedor `forms`, así la altura de `forms` se adaptará lo máximo posible según hasta donde lleguen sus elementos de adentro:

```
.container .forms {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: max-content; /* le doy una altura máxima */
  width: 200%;
  transition: height 0.2s ease;
}
```

Y el problema del botón, eran estas propiedades:

```
.form .input-field {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

No vendría a ser necesario que el botón tengan estas propiedades, así que los quité, sólo dejemos que las clases de bootstrap (que tiene tu botón) haga su trabajo:

```
<div class="bstr d-grid col-12 mx-auto"> <!-- con estas clases vendría suficiente -->
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="botonRegistrar">Registrar</button>
</div>
```

Código completo:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

body {
  background: #504157;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}


/* ------------- FORMULARIO ------------- */

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 430px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 11px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.container .forms {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: max-content;
  width: 200%;
  transition: height 0.2s ease;
}

.container .form {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: margin-left 0.18s ease;
  border-radius: 11px;
}

.container .form .title {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.form .title::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -9%;
  height: 3px;
  width: 119.7%;
  background-color: #4070f4;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.form .bstr button {
  border-color: #4070f4;
  font-display: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #4070f4;
  padding: 11px;
}

.bstr button:hover {
  background-color: #145D56;
  border-color: #145D56;
}

.container .btn2 {
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #145D56;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.container .btn2 i {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2-bootstrap-5-theme@1.3.0/dist/select2-bootstrap-5-theme.min.css" />
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ===== CSS ===== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-left: 6%;">
      <a href="#">
        <button type="button" class="btn2 btn-primary"><i class="uil uil-arrow-circle-left"></i> Inicio</button>
      </a>
      <div class="forms">
        <div class="form login" style="height: 90%;">
          <span class="title" style="margin-bottom: 30%">Registro</span><br><br><br>

          <form method="POST">
            <div class="input-field">
              <!-- TESTEAR CON EL TEXTO CORTO Y EL TEXTO LARGO -->
              <!-- <h4 style="font-size: large;">Libro seleccionado: = Bioquimica</h4> -->
              <h4 style="font-size: large;">Libro seleccionado: = La preparación física en el voleibol y el desarrollo de la fuerza en los deportes de carácter explosivo-balístico.</h4>
              <hr>
              <h4 style="font-size: large;">Fecha de Inicio = 07/03/2023</h4>
              <hr>
              <h4 style="font-size: large;">Fecha de Devolución = 14/03/2023</h4><br><br>
            </div>
            <div class="bstr d-grid col-12 mx-auto">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="botonRegistrar">Registrar</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excelente Cris, muy clara la explicación. Está 10 puntos ahora el formulario con tus modificaciones, saludos